# Insert into Multiple Columns from a Grouped by Subquery

Tags: sql, subquery

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B, COLUMN_C)              -- Line 1
SELECT 'Label A',                                             -- Line 2
(SELECT CATEGORY, COUNT(1) FROM SUB_TABLE GROUP BY CATEGORY); -- Line 3, need help
```

**Result from Line 3**

[image: Result from Line 3]

**What I want to achieve**

- 'Label A' to be inserted into COLUMN_A
- Grouped by CATEGORY from Line 3 to be inserted into COLUMN_B
- Grouped by COUNT(1) from Line 3 to be inserted into COLUMN_C

**Expected Result**

[image: Expected Result]

I encountered an error: "subquery must return only one column". How can I achieve the expected result?

Comment: Use nothing but `SELECT 'Label A', CATEGORY, COUNT(1) FROM SUB_TABLE GROUP BY CATEGORY`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I encountered an error: "INSERT has more target columns than expressions".

Comment: you're welcome. There should be no problem for the current case, since there are three columns in the SELECT list versus three columns following `INSERT INTO table`

Comment: You are right. Your answer worked, thank you. I tested with 2 additional columns after the 3rd column and added corresponding 2 columns in the INSERT as well to match 5v5, but somehow I had to switch the orders to be Column_A, Column_B, Column_D (new), Column_E (new), Column C before it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like below if want to use subsqery

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B, COLUMN_C)              -
SELECT 'Label A', CATEGORY,  cnt from                                          
(SELECT CATEGORY, COUNT(1) as cnt FROM SUB_TABLE GROUP BY CATEGORY) a
```

in fact don't need sub-query

```
 INSERT INTO TABLE (COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B, COLUMN_C)              -
SELECT 'Label A', CATEGORY,  COUNT(1) as cnt from                                          
  FROM SUB_TABLE GROUP BY CATEGORY
```

[demo link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fbfa6993266296ec3501a436cad71620)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I encountered the same error for both options: "INSERT has more target columns than expressions".

Comment: @Mysophobe check the demo https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fbfa6993266296ec3501a436cad71620

Comment: You are right. Your answer worked as well, thank you and
Barbaros Özhan. I tested with 2 additional columns after the 3rd column and added corresponding 2 columns in the INSERT as well to match 5v5, but somehow I had to switch the orders to be Column_A, Column_B, Column_D (new), Column_E (new), Column C before it worked.